# Examples in physics or engineering in which choice of branches of complex root or log make differences

Tags: complex-analysis, multivalued-functions

Are there any nontrivial examples in physics or engineering in which a choice of the branch of complex root or log matters to obtain the "correct" solution of the problem? Of course, I'll not choose a branch of square root such that $\sqrt{1}=-1$ when the value in the problem should be finally real. I need some nontrivial examples.